# detect browser in perl,how to check if the browser is internet explorer(IE) in perl

Tags: javascript, perl

```
$msg_box_ok_id=smthin;
print<<HTML_alert;
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

    if (browserName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
        $msg_box_ok_id=somthinnew;      
    }
</script>
HTML_alert
;
```

I'm using this code but javascript can't identify the variable.

so the variable $msg_box_ok_id doesn't change.

Comment: Do you think you can set a perl variable from javascript? You should read some basic books on how internet works. Javascripts happens on the client side, perl on the server side.

Comment: choroba, please be a little mor polite at all. Your comment is wrong by the way. Javascript may also be running at serversie (node.js for example). But a short google question would have answerded that question.

Answer (score 6):

This code can't work.

I assume your Perl code is running at the webserver, but your JavaScript is running at the client-PC.

So the JavaScript code cannot influence the program-logic at the server this way.

Take a look at the examples for the [HTTP::BrowserDetect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3a%3aBrowserDetect) module.

By the way, browser detection in JavaScript won't work either this way:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nav_useragent.asp

```
/* check the agent */  
 function checkBrowserName(name){  
   var agent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();  
   if (agent.indexOf(name.toLowerCase())>-1) {  
     return true;  
   }  
   return false;  
 }  


if(checkBrowserName('MSIE')){  
  alert('Internet Explorer!');  
}
```